# visualworks smalltalk show graphic image on canvas

Tags: screen, show, image, smalltalk

What is the right way to show graphic image on canvas?
I have object aImage from:

```
(ImageReader fromFile: 'clockface.jpg') image.
```

I made via GUIBuilder(new canvas->install) new Class called ClockWindow:

```
 (...)superclass: #{UI.ApplicationModel}(...)
```

and method initialize:

```
initialize
|img  gc|
img:=(ImageReader fromFile: 'clockface.jpg') image.
img convertForGraphicsDevice: Screen default.
gc := ScreenGraphicsContext new.
img displayOn: gc.
gc displayOn: self.
```

but I got error:
messageNotUnderstood: representImage: anImage forMedium: medium
in line with: " img displayOn: gc."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a label with an image.  Here's how:

1. Define a class method called clockFace which returns the image

> ```
> clockFace
>   <resource: #image>
>   ^(ImageReader fromFile: 'clockface.jpg') image
> ```

1. Add a Label to the UI
2. Click on "Label Is Image"
3. For the message, use #clockFace

It will be slow to load the clock face image from a file all the time.  To fix that, go to the clockFace method, choose "Edit" then in the ImageEditor use "install".  This replaces the code that loads the image from a file with an equivalent method that stores the image in a method.

For extra brownie points, you can create another class method to give you a CachedImage.  A CachedImage will redisplay on a UI faster because it doesn't have to convert the image into the screen's palette each time it displays.  Just create a class method called clockFaceCachedImage like this:

> ```
> clockFaceCachedImage
>   ^CachedImage on: self clockFace
> ```

You can now use clockFaceCachedImage as the message for the label.

Comment: So. Let's go level up. I want to draw some shapes and images on a graphic context. How to display this context as a part of canvas (GuiPainter)?

Comment: For that you want a custom view.  Create a subclass of View and override displayOn: to draw your graphics on the graphics context.  To add it to a UIPainter window, add a viewHolder and for the View: field, enter the name of a method in your class that returns the custom view.  You probably want to cache it in an instance variable once you create it.